# How to give a wakelock to an app?

Tags: applications, power-on, wakelock

How can I give a CPU wakelock to an app so that It can **work even when the screen is off?**

(Usually android halts CPU too, when screen is off)

Comment: Apps get wakelocks programmatically using [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager) APIs. You can acquire and release a wakelock manually by writing a string to `/sys/power/wake_lock` and `/sys/power/wake_unlock` respectively.

Comment: @IrfanLatif  Thank you! :) That's the answer, though I don't have root :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have root access in your phone, there are many apps in the Play Store which can take a **partial wake lock**. Just start the app **manually** when you need it. Because, if one app takes a partial wake lock, other apps can also take the advantage.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the wakelock affects other apps too. and I don't have root :)